# Which response headers are making Squid's refresh_pattern ineffective?

Tags: cache, squid

I cannot get Squid to cache anything with the following origin response headers.

When I use curl repeatedly, I get the following response

```
> curl -s -D - -o /dev/null -x "http://localhost:3128" http://my-domain.com/test.jpeg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: undefined
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Cache-Control: private, no-transform, max-age=0
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 12:44:00 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
X-Cache: MISS from b6cf67dac785
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from b6cf67dac785:3128
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 google, 1.1 b6cf67dac785 (squid/4.13)
Connection: keep-alive
```

It looks like it finds the image in its cache, but revalidates with the server and then gets a fresh copy from the server?

I don't want it to revalidate first - it needs to serve it straight out of the cache. I am the only client of Squid - and I want to force every single image to be cached regardless of the headers of the origin server. I know this breaks HTTP accepted protocols - but I still want to **force** Squid to **cache absolutely everything**. (it will only ever fetch images)

This is my refresh_pattern directive I am using

```
refresh_pattern . 525600 100% 525600 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store reload-into-ims ignore-must-revalidate ignore-private ignore-auth store-stale
```

**I can't see which of the response headers are rendering my refresh_pattern ineffective?**

I have also the following two directives set. With or without them - there is no difference.

```
minimum_expiry_time 1 year
max_stale 1 year
```

For reference, I also attach response headers that do cache well with my current refresh_pattern.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-goog-generation: 1613049999992692
x-goog-metageneration: 3
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 159962
x-goog-meta-: 
x-goog-custom-time: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
Content-Type: image/jpeg
x-goog-hash: crc32c=6EwUgA==
x-goog-hash: md5=OGlL99uyN7kr4j0umpn5pw==
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-GUploader-UploadID: ABg5-UwYGdi405Mc_A1_ppi6O7NIXd3UKOpqbzcj1WvMzVN-N3U1hb-O_FdSGdBt5ZPDWU63egT-kwi4lrx8RVu4k_0
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 13:27:47 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-transform, max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 13:27:47 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 13:26:40 GMT
ETag: "38694bf7dbb237b92be23d2e9a99f9a7"
Content-Length: 0
Server: UploadServer
Age: 0
X-Cache: HIT from b6cf67dac785
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from b6cf67dac785:3128
Via: 1.1 b6cf67dac785 (squid/4.13)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Do you also have `max_stale` and `minimum_expiry_time` matching the refresh pattern time?  Do you have an ACL on the cache like `cache allow blah` and if so, is jpg in that ACL?  Do you have `cache_store_log` and `cache_log` defined and did you try setting `debug_options 28,3` to debug the cache?

Comment: I have set the cache_store_log and cache_log options but I can't seem the generate any log files with it. I am using b4tman/docker-squid and have set both log locations to /var/log/squid ... I have amended the question with those additional directives that I have set

Comment: If logging to disk does not work, try `cache_store_log stdio:/dev/stdout` and `cache_log stdio:/dev/stdout`.  and be sure to set `debug_options 28,3` in the config with a comment that reminds you to disable that later.  Ability to see the logs is important, or you would be guessing.

Comment: The first time I get TCP_MISS/200, the second time TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/200. Beyond that I don't seen any additional logs in stdout with those settings

Comment: What is the full version of squid you are using?  Asking because there have been changes that affected some of your settings.  some are ignored.  Its actually hard to follow, but 3.1 to 3.2, some of the refresh ignore directives follow RFC's even if you tell it not to.  4.x also changes the behavior again.

Comment: Hey Aaron - I am using 4.13

Comment: I think that the only way to force cache with google in this case would be to have two layers of caching.  One layer to strip off all the non standard headers (google headers) and one that does the caching.  Happy to have someone with more squid background correct me.  You could try blocking the headers on that squid instance, but I think it's too late at that point in the cache query logic.   Sorry I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Remember though, the one with all the Google headers is the one that caches properly ... It's the first set of headers where the caching doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same case and the same issue, except I think Squid isn't caching certain items because they require BasicAuth to be fetched. Not sure how to force it to cache these as well. @Joerg did you have any luck with this?